# Using existing record of a parent class in Spring JPA/Java

Tags: java, inheritance, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm developing a solution, and in a determinated situation I have a class called Cliente, as follow

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Cliente implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String nome;
private String email;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="TELEFONE")
private Set<String> telefones = new HashSet<>();

public Cliente() {}

//getters and setters
}
```

And I have a class Funcionario that extends class Cliente, as follow.

```
@Entity
public class Funcionario extends Cliente{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String cpf;
private String cargo;
private Double salario;
private String login;
private String senha;
private String perfil;

public Funcionario() {}

public Funcionario(Integer id, String nome, String email, String cpf, String cargo, Double salario, String login, String senha, String perfil) {
    super(id, nome, email);
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.cargo = cargo;
    this.salario = salario;
    this.login = login;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.perfil = perfil;
}

//getters and setter
}
```

In my database, I have two table when the application starts. The table Funcionario, and the table Cliente. And in the table Funcionario I have a field called "Id" that relates a record on Funcionario to a record on Cliente.

[Fields of table Cliente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t5TT.png)

[Fields of table Funcionario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pa1n.png)

When I need to save a record in the class Funcionario, I need to pass the parameters "Id", "Nome" and "Email" to the super contructor, and a new record on Funcionario table and Cliente table is created.

So far, it seems that everything is working well, but in sometime I will need to use an existing record of the class Cliente. In other words, I will have to insert a new record on table Funcionario, but I need to use a record that already exists in table Cliente.

I Searched a lot but I didn't find something helpful, to do this. Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Thank you, very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work with JPA because it really contradicts how inheritance works in Java. You would have to load a `Cliente` instance and then somehow turn it into a `Funcionario` instance.

I see two possible approaches to solve the problem.

1. The hacky way: Use an insert statement to create some dummy data in the `Funcionario` table. *After* that load the entity and it should come out as a `Funcionario`
2. The clean way: Change your object model. `Funcionario` should not extend `Cliente` but instead `Funcionario` should be an optional one-to-one reference in `Cliente`. It would probably be a good idea to rename it to the Spanish(?) equivalent of `FuncionarioRole` so a `Cliente` might have a `FuncionarioRole`. This way the change to a `Functionario` is just adding a reference. If you share the id, of the two entities it might even match to the same database schema.

Comment: I thought this possibility, of changing my object model. But I didn't thought this model couldn't be possible to implement. Well, you have clarified my mind! Thank you very much!!